# How to change the default terminal in JetBrains Fleet to Git Bash?

Tags: jetbrains-fleet

Is there a way to change the default terminal in Fleet to Git Bash? On windows and mac, they are set to the OS default. I would like to use `Git Bash` in stead.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps to open integrated git bash in Jetbrains Fleet:

1. Open Fleet
2. Goto Settings and search for terminal settings
3. Click on Edit in settings.json
4. Add the following code in your settings.json file

```
"terminal.profiles": [
  {
    "program": "<Installation-Path-For-Git>/bin/bash.exe",
    "args": ["--login"],
    "name": "Git Bash"
  }
]
```

Note: The please provide the proper installation path for git. In my case git is installed in C:/Program Files/Git. So my path will be **C:/Program Files/Git/bin/bash.exe**

Comment: You will need to add the arguments from my answer or the terminal won't recognize any key words.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the setting in VS Code, if you have Git Bash as a default profile for the terminal you can see the path to the program that you want to fire in the terminal window and the arguments.

Here is for my personal machiene:

```
"terminal.profiles": [
     {
         "program": "<path-to-terminal-program>",
         "args":["--login", "-i"],
         "name": "Git bash"
     }
 ]
```

Note: These arguments are for Git Bash.